# genie.exe produces a Solution and Visual Studio can't build it

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use `genie.exe` to build a Visual Studio solution, but when I right-click on a file to compile it, this error occurs:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\path-to-desktop\vs2015_genie\obj\x32\Debug\test\source\bgfx\debugview.obj': No such file or directory
```

When I create the needed subfolders by hand, Visual Studio can build the `.obj` file. But why doesn't generate Visual Studio the needed folders automatically?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never hear of `genie`. Is this what you are talking about? https://github.com/bkaradzic/GENie

Comment: @drescherjm Yea, that's it

Comment: Are you sure there's no any typo somewhere?

Comment: @RyanB Surely no typo, added some pics so you can see. Visual Studio just can't make the 2 middle folders "\source\bgfx\". When I create them by hand, everything works

Comment: If you `cd` manually using command prompt to that directory and you `dir` it, can you find the .obj file?

Comment: @RyanB Nope, otherwise I would have seen it in Explorer as well, since I went to that folder to create the two missing subfolders. When the two subfolders exists, VS can build the .cpp file

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: @Banex Just tried to compile the file with VS as administrator, but it won't generate the two needed subfolders as well